Solve $16x^4=81$

Solve $16x^4=81$

$x^4=\dfrac{81}{16}$
$x=\pm\dfrac{3}{2}$
But apparently there are complex solutions as well:
$16x^4-81=0$
$(4x^2)^2-9^2=0$
$(4x^2+9)(4x^2-9)=0$
$x^2=\pm\dfrac{9}{4}$
If $x^2=\dfrac{9}{4}$, then $x=\pm\dfrac{3}{2}$.
If $x^2=-\dfrac{9}{4}$, then $x=\pm\dfrac{3i}{2}$
My question is if I approach this problem the first way, I will completely miss the complex solutions. Why? This seems dangerous to me because intuitively I will always go with the first way and would never think of solving this the second way.

Your first method is just wrong...if $x^4=a>0$ then we can take square roots to get $x^2=\pm \sqrt a$ so now you have to solve both $x^2=\sqrt a$ and $x^2=-\sqrt a$ (not simultaneously, we only know that $x$ must satisfy one of these).Thus getting $4$ solutions, as you should.

$\frac{81}{16}=\frac{81}{16}i^4$

@BoweiTang That's a greeaat way to analyse it. I never even though of it

Luckily we know that any 4th degree polynomial has exactly 4 solutions (which may repeat or be complex) this applies to any nth degree polynomial it has n solutions. From here we can see we missed two solutions

It's just something you have to drum into your head, that a degree $n$ polynomial will always have $n$ roots, and that often some of them will be complex. You must train yourself to look for complex solutions as well. There is no way around it.

By the Fundamental theorem of algebra, if $p(x)$ is a polynomial with complex (possibly all real) coefficients of degree $n$, then equation $p(x) = 0$ has precisely $n$ solutions, counted with multiplicities.
If you have equation $x^n = a$ for $a\in\mathbb C$, most generally you can solve it by using De Moivre's formula. In short, you write $a = r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)$ for a positive real number $r$ and some angle $\varphi$ and then all solutions are given by the formula
$$ x_k = \sqrt[n]r \left(\cos\frac{\varphi+2k\pi}{n}+i\sin\frac{\varphi+2k\pi}{n}\right),\ k=0,1,\ldots,n-1,\tag{1}$$ where $\sqrt[n]{\,\cdot\,}\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ is the standard real $n$-th root function, the inverse to the function $x\mapsto x^n\colon [0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$.
For example, if we have equation $x^2 = \frac{81}{16}$, then, we can write $\frac{81}{16} = \frac{81}{16}(\cos 0+i\sin 0)$, so we have two solutions $$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{81}{16}}\left(\cos\frac{0+2\cdot 0\cdot\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{0+2\cdot 0\cdot\pi}{2}\right) = \frac 94(\cos 0 + i\sin 0) = \frac 94,$$
$$x_1=\sqrt{\frac{81}{16}}\left(\cos\frac{0+2\cdot 1\cdot\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{0+2\cdot 1\cdot\pi}{2}\right) = \frac 94(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi) = -\frac 94.$$
Of course, this is overkill, since we know that we can write $x_{0,1} = \pm\sqrt{\frac{81}{16}},$ but my point is that the "$\pm$" part comes from the  trigonometric part of formula $(1)$.
Let's now consider equation $x^2 = -\frac94$. We can write $-\frac 94 =\frac 94(\cos\pi+i\sin\pi)$, so the solutions now become
$$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}}\left(\cos\frac{\pi+2\cdot 0\cdot\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi+2\cdot 0\cdot\pi}{2}\right) = \frac 32(\cos \frac\pi 2 + i\sin\frac\pi 2) = \frac 32i,$$
$$x_1=\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}}\left(\cos\frac{\pi+2\cdot 1\cdot\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi+2\cdot 1\cdot\pi}{2}\right) = \frac 32(\cos \frac{3\pi} 2 + i\sin\frac{3\pi} 2) = -\frac 32i.$$ Usually, we'd write something like this $x_{0,1} = \pm\sqrt{-\frac 94} = \pm i\sqrt\frac 94 = \pm\frac 32i.$
Now, for the equation $x^4 = \frac{81}{9}$, I will leave it to you for exercise to solve it by formula $(1)$. Usually, we can just solve it by using the short-cuts we just discussed above:
$$x^4 = \frac{81}{9} \implies x^2 = \pm \frac 94 \implies x^2 = \frac 94\text{ or }x^2 = -\frac 94\implies x = \pm \frac32\text{ or } x = \pm\frac 32i.$$

Another point of view we can adapt is to use formulas $x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)$ and $x^2+a^2 = x^2 - (ia)^2 = (x-ia)(x+ia)$ for $a>0$, so $$x^4 - \frac{81}{16} = \left(x^2-\frac94\right)\left(x^2+\frac94\right) = \left(x-\frac 32\right)\left(x+\frac 32\right)\left(x-\frac32i\right)\left(x+\frac32i\right)$$ which gives us all four solutions as above because $x^4 = \frac{81}{16}$ if and only if $x^4-\frac{81}{16} = 0$ if and only if $\left(x-\frac 32\right)\left(x+\frac 32\right)\left(x-\frac32i\right)\left(x+\frac32i\right)=0$

I will say it bluntly, downvoting standard high school answer to this question is extremely idiotic, for the lack of better word. I would self-report this comment if I could, so please someone do it for me. Especially when the downvoter didn't even read it and immediately pressed the button.

I have upvoted your answer.

In order to avoid the case of only getting the two real solutions, we should keep in mind that any degree 4 polynomial with complex coefficients (i.e., on $\mathbb{C}[x]$) has 4 roots, counting the multiplicities.
Clearly, the two "easier" roots: $\pm \frac{3}{2}$ are indeed some roots of $x^4-\frac{81}{16}$. But they are not all of them. To make sure we find all roots, we should further find the roots of $\frac{x^4-\frac{81}{16}}{(x-\frac{3}{2})(x+\frac{3}{2})}=x^2+\frac{9}{4}$.

that's quite an overkill don't you think?

Your first approach is just fine, but remember:
$$x^4=\frac{81}{16}\implies x=\frac{3}{2}\times\text{the $4^{th}$ roots of unity }$$
So
$$x=-\frac{3}{2}\lor x=-\frac{3i}{2}\lor x=\frac{3i}{2}\lor x=\frac{3}{2}$$
I suggest you read this Wikipedia page.

I don't understand. When I see $x^4=\dfrac{81}{16}$, I will automatically think of $x=\pm\dfrac{3}{2}$. There's no way I would think of $x=\pm\dfrac{3}{2} \times 1^{\frac{1}{4}}$. I know it's mathematically correct, but isn't the $1^{\frac{1}{4}}$ unnecessary?

@ronaldchristenkkson Actually it is $$z^4=\frac{81}{16}\implies z=\pm \frac{3}{2} \text{or} z=\pm i \frac{3}{2}$$ . Because $1,-1,i,-i$ are the $4^{th}$ roots of unity since $1^4=(-1)^4=i^4=(-i)^4=1$

Here's an interesting fact! For any $k\in\mathbb{Z},$ then $^{n}\sqrt{1}=e^{\frac{2\pi ik}{n}}.$ (These are called the $n^{\text{th}}$roots of unity.)
Let $I_n$ denote the collection of all $n^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity. Then $x^4=\frac{81}{16}$ iff $x=\frac{3}{2}y$ for some $y\in I_n.$
